# Java refers to lib java.lang.String not my java.lang.String

Tags: java, oop

I have created a class with the same name and package as the String java class.

```
package java.lang;

public class String {

    public String() {
        System.out.println("This is my string ");
    }
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("From show mathod .");
    }
}
```

When I try to invoke this show method it gives error for no such method. It refers to API class. why.?

```
import java.lang.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = new String();
        str.show();
    }
}
```

I know that I am violating the rule of unique package and class name. But I want to know if I add two jars in my class-path and they have same structure. In such case is there any behaviour defined by Java which class will be loaded.

And why java does not load my class instead of Java API classes? (I also tried this with other api defined classes)

**#Please do not give answer like I am violating the rule or work arounds.**

Comment: rename your package and try again.

Comment: give your fully qualified path instead

Comment: Fully qualified class name, like `java.lang.String` or `joe.lib.MyClass`, is supposed to be unique in Java world (at least, for well-known names, such as `java.*`). You violate this principle here.

Comment: I just want to know why java behaves this way.? Suppose someday I add two jar both have one class with same structure then..?

Comment: @VictorSorokin ya I know u are right, But in such violation is there any defined way for the class loader to which class will be loaded.

Comment: this might help http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week4/30.html

Comment: @sakhunzai In my case I have same package name also. This link states about Same class name.

Comment: For other examples not related to Java's base classes, look into _JAR hell_.

Comment: I led to one thing that is if I try to use any core java class as same package and class name then it will not work. But in case of any third party api, even servlet api if I define a class with same package and class then It will load my class. Tested with spring classes, Mysql, Servlet, One own Jar.

Comment: @ankitkatiyar91 Have you seen my answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24547874/162634 JRE `java.*` classes are loaded by JVM itself and `ClassLoader` subsystem prevents you from custom loading of _any_ class in `java.*` package.

Comment: Yup I have seen your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java comes shipped with classes. One of these classes is java.lang.String.
These pre-shipped classes take precedence in the classpath over any class that you might write that have the same package and name.

Whenever you do a `new java.lang.String()`, regardless if you have a class with the same package and name, the runtime class shipped by Oracle will take precedence.

Since java.lang.String is also a final class, there's no way you will be able to add new methods to it. The best solution is for you to create a new class in a different package or under a different name.

Comment: Is not the first sentence a bit misleading?

Comment: I mean, he is not extending the class `java.lang.String`.

Comment: I don't see any other feasible answer.. Perhaps loading the class dynamically could help (provided the absolute package name of  both the String class implementations don't match..). But still using class loaders seems like an overkill..

Comment: I believe this answer is correct, but there is a way around it (untested): Using `-Xbootclasspath/p:path` you can prepend a JAR, and this will indeed take precedence then.

Answer (score 1):

classes can not be redefined after the VM has started and the class has been loaded.  As java.lang.String is being used way before your code, it would already be loaded.

I am not sure that you could even achieve this using a byte code enhancement library like  javassist

Answer (score 1):

Just tried to write custom `ClassLoader` to load my class named `java.lang.String`. Ran out of luck here:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.lang
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:658)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:794)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at temp.TempLoader.findClass(TempLoader.java:20)
    at temp.TempLoader.main(TempLoader.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Offending code in JRE `java.lang.ClassLoader`:

```
    if ((name != null) && name.startsWith("java.")) {
        throw new SecurityException
            ("Prohibited package name: " +
             name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf('.')));
    }
```

It would be interesting to see any "pure Java" solution (not involving out-of-JVM changes to runtime) which can workaround this.

You may wonder how JVM itself loads `java.*` classes? Well, they loaded by so called *bootstrap loader*, during initialization of JVM instance. I assume, there's no public API to that classloader.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do exactly, but I can suggest a different approach.

In java `String` class is `final`, so, it can't be extended. Create a *wrapper class* which has your additional methods and a String field.. Now you can define and call `show()` on your class  (You can't do it on the String directly..)  If `split()`  is called on your class, then just delegate the call to String class's `split()`.

expose a method getInstance() in your wrapper . Whenever myWrapper.getInstance() is called, call new String() from there..

Comment: I am not extending anything. Just want know if this case occur what is defined behaviour for class loader to load classes.

Comment: @ankitkatiyar91 - See.. first of all you can't load 2 String classes with the same absolute package name at the same time.. Next my approach still allows  you / other parts of your code to use the default String class. This is very important to maintain sanity of Java programs . There are other classes which will be indirectly referencing the default String class. Your custom String class will need to behave in exactly the same way.. Delegating responsibility is perhaps the best way to handle such conditions..